# Python Kivy ScrollView Problem of size_hint

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, scrollview, kivymd

**main.py file :**

```
    class stacklayout(StackLayout):
        def __init__(self,**kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
            size= dp(100)
            for i in range(0,100):
                b = Button(text=str(i+1), size_hint=(None,None),size=(size,size))
                self.add_widget(b)
```

**bot.kv file :**

```
    Scroll:
    
    <Scroll@ScrollView>:
        stacklayout:
            size_hint:1,None
            height: self.minimum_height
    
    
    <stacklayout>:
        # padding: ...
```

**Error I am getting :**

```
size_hint:1,None
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I had tried enough to solve but no success.

Comment: from where does `size_hint:1,None` comes?

Comment: from kv code, bot.kv

Answer (score 0):

Change your class name from `stacklayout` to `Stacklayout`. Any class names in `kv` should start with upper case and not following that rule can cause syntax errors.

Comment: Thank you so much, it work 100%.
I am really grateful to you :)